# All I was saying "is" ... or All I was saying "was"

Tags: verbs, tenses

Which of these is more appropriate?

> All I was saying **is** that you're the more responsible one

or

> All I was saying **was** that you're the more responsible one

Both feel correct to me.

Comment: And sometimes we use "All *am* saying is ..." even though it is something I have just said.

Comment: We also — some of us — say: *Alls I’m saying is...*

Comment: One argument goes that an utterance, direct or reported, (in this case, *You’re the more responsible one*) is static, existing outside of time, so it continues to be what one said, even long after it’s saying. By that logic, it’s *All I was saying **is***.

Comment: @PaulTanenbaum Unless you've since changed your mind. Then you'd say "All I was saying was X, but now I say Y."

Comment: All I am saying is give peace as chance.

Answer (score 2):

> All I was saying was ...

You are clarifying what you said.

> All I was saying is ...

You are clarifying what you said and standing by what you said. But perhaps it would be best in that case to say

> All I'm saying is ...

Answer (score 1):

### Depends when you were saying it

“is” is immediate or continuous in time and the first is better if you are referring to something you just said or said a short time ago or something you said in the past but that you still believe.

“was” refers to a past event and is more appropriate if you are referring to something you said last year, or yesterday, or 10-minutes ago.

The exact line between “now” and “then” depends on context but if you are referencing a conversation that has ended it’s probably a “was”, if it’s a conversation you’re still in, it’s an “is”.

For completeness, you can use “will be” for something you’re planning to say in the future. Perhaps you have to introduce your acquaintance at a formal event and this is the gist of your speech.

Comment: I agree (although 'All I am saying is that you're the more responsible one' is probably more likely for a very recent communication). Could you add a couple of respectable-looking examples from the internet?